# SQL Query need to display all record

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have table Question table with the following columns and data

```
QuestionId QuestionText
1            what is my name
2             xxx
3             yyy
```

and I have ExamQuestionAnswer table with following columns and data

```
ExamId QuestionID  Answer
1          1        abc
1          2        def
2          1        abc
2          2        xyz
```

Now I want to display all questions and answers for the examid ,irrespective of question answered or not.

Please help me with query

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PranayRana That's good advice, I hope you will get it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT  A.ExamID ,
        Q.QuestionID ,
        Q.QuestionText ,
        ISNULL(A.Answer, '-') Answer
FROM    dbo.Question Q WITH ( NOLOCK )
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ExamQuestionAnswer A WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON Q.QuestionId = 
A.QuestionId
```

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to user outer join between both tables will do work for you.

```
select t1.QuestionId, t1.QuestionText,  ISNULL(t2.Answer,'') as Answer
 from Question t1
left outer join ExamQuestionAnswer t2 
  on t1.QuestionId = t2.QuestionId
```

check here : [SQL LEFT JOIN Keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)  , [ISNULL (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Try joining them:

```
SELECT *
FROM QuestionId t1
     JOIN ExamQuestionAnswer t2 ON t1.QuestionId = t2.QuestionID
WHERE t2.ExamId = [X];
```

Where `[X]` is your `Exam ID`

Answer (score 0):

I would offer a slight variation where we display a meaningful message if a given question has really never been answered:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t2.ExamId, 0) AS ExamId,   -- display 0 for non matches
    t1.QuestionId,
    t1.QuestionText,
    COALESCE(t2.Answer, 'Never answered') AS Answer
FROM Question t1
LEFT JOIN ExamQuestionAnswer t2
    ON t1.QuestionId = t2.QuestionId;
```

[image]

Per request I added the `ExamId` to the select list.  A value of zero is shown for `ExamId` of non matching questions.

### Demo

Comment: Need Results in this format  ExamID,QuestionID,QuestionText,Answer

Comment: pls help me with query,

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.ExamId AS 'Exam Id',
    q.QuestionId AS 'Question Id',
    q.QuestionText AS 'Question Text',
    IS NULL(e.Answer, 'No Answer') AS 'Answer'
FROM Question q LEFT JOIN ExamQuestionAnswer e
ON q.QuestionId = e.QuestionId
```